# How do I attend Skype interviews while being employed?

Tags: hiring

I have to attend Skype interviews for new positions. However, I am still employed. Would it be best to work at home to be able to attend these interviews?

Comment: How long do you expect each interview to last?  How many and how frequent are they?  Please [edit] more information into your question.  Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

From home and on your own time. Take a half-day of vacation, or use your lunch break, or flextime. Just as you would if interviewing locally.

(@JoeStrazzere makes a very good point. Any company interviewing by Skype or similar should expect requests for after-hours calls, so there's no harm in asking. In fact, they should understand that your not wanting to do this on your current employer's timemeans you'd show them the same respect. And if they say no, that may tell you something about their corporate culture.)

Comment: +1. To specify, unless you have been fired from your current employment or have already handed in your resignation, your current employer has no obligation to make the time for you to attend interviews for other companies. You will therefore have to attend them in your own time. If you can only schedule these during the hours that you normally work, you'll have to take time off.

Answer (score 1):

Three guidelines:

1. Have control and privacy over the space you are in. Coffee shops can have spotty wifi. You may be able to find a private room in your office but I would be leery especially if you are trying to be highly discreet. Home is best.
2. Do not dishonestly take time away from work. If leaving your desk for a phone call, lunch, coffee with a friend or colleague, etc. is routine then you can leave your desk for this reason. However when it comes to a half-day interview you will definitely want to take a vacation day or otherwise take a personal day, *not* a sick day.
3. Expect your interviewer to cooperate with you. If circumstances are really untenable, there's after-hours or you can knock it down to a phone, video-less interview.

Answer (score 0):

You could choose a location near your work (a coffee shop) with Wifi access preferable in a quiet section.  Always use your own equipment for the interview.  Do a mockup Skype call from the location ahead of time to eliminate any access problems or noise related issues.

Comment: I would not recommend doing a Skype (or even a phone) interview in a space you have no control over.  Go home, find a quiet room, and do the interview there.

Comment: I generally agree with @JamesAdam about not doing it from within the shop; but if you have a car, buying something to drink and then using their wifi from within the parking lot might be an option.

Comment: @DanNeely the wifi itself is the unreliable thing.